# Lifecycle of Activity instances

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I have the following Activity:

```
public class StartActivity extends Activity
{
    String str = "somestring";
    int number = "1";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Code here
    }
}
```

I read the following on the Android docs (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

*If an activity is completely obscured by another activity, it is stopped. It still retains all state and member information, however, it is no longer visible to the user so its window is hidden and it will often be killed by the system when memory is needed elsewhere.*

Does this mean that my class instances (**str** and **number**) are "alive" and available unless **onDestroy** is called or memory is needed after **onPause** or **onStop** is called?

Comment: Why are you asking? What is it that you want to do?

Comment: Those variables will still be "alive", as you call it, until you call finish, or the os decides to destroy it (maybe calling onDestroy() maybe not).  If you want those variables to persist, it would be a good idea to save your activities state in the onPause() method, which will get called whenever your activity goes to the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in your caller activity, you have called `finish()` method, then no instances of previous activity will be alive since you have finished caller activity. All the instances will be garbage collected.

But if your caller activity, does not call `finish()`, then the activity will no longer be visible but, it will be present on the activity stack maintained by the operating system. The caller activity (i.e. the previous activity) may get finished in cases when the device is low in memory like in cases, ex.: if the activity calls Camera (which requires rich resources), in that case the previous activity may get destroyed.

So in your case, the variables will be alive even if `StartActivity` is not the present visible activity.

Comment: This isn't completely correct. Android will never call `finish()` on an activity if the device is low on memory. In that case Android will just kill the process that is hosting that activity, without calling any lifecycle methods on it at all (ie: it won't call `onDestroy()`

Comment: @ David: I haven't said that finish() method will be called for an activity if device is in low memory. I said it will be destroyed by the operating system.

Comment: You wrote **"The caller activity (i.e. the previous activity) may get finished in cases when the device is low in memory"** I was just responding to that. This is a common misunderstanding.

Comment: Ohh yeah its misunderstanding. I meant, the activity will get finished (means destroyed :-)) only.